# How to get the associated data using the foreign key

Tags: haskell, yesod, one-to-one, persistent

I am trying to write a function that look for the profile of a user or create one if it doesn't exists.

I have used getBy and selectFirst to get the profile of a given user, but I get this error:

Couldn't match type ‘HandlerFor site0’ with ‘Key’

I am using the scaffolding site with postgres.

This is my model (user and profile have a one-to-one relationship)

```
User
    email Text
    password Text Maybe
    verkey Text Maybe
    verified Bool
    UniqueUser email                                                                                                   
    deriving Typeable

Profile 
    name Text                                                                                                          
    userId UserId
    UniqueName name
    UniqueUserId userId
    deriving Typeable
```

The function is as follow:

```
getOrCreateProfile :: UserId -> ProfileId
getOrCreateProfile userId = do
    mProfile <- runDB $ getBy $ UniqueUserId userId                                                                    
    case mProfile of
        Just (Entity pid _) -> return pid
        Nothing  -> undefined -- insert profile
```

The error I am getting is:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘HandlerFor site0’ with ‘Key’
      Expected type: Key (Maybe (Entity Profile))
        Actual type: HandlerFor site0 (Maybe (Entity Profile))
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        mProfile <- runDB $ getBy $ UniqueUserId userId
      In the expression:
        do mProfile <- runDB $ getBy $ UniqueUserId userId
           case mProfile of
             Just (Entity pid _) -> pid
             Nothing -> undefined
      In an equation for ‘getOrCreateProfile’:
          getOrCreateProfile userId
            = do mProfile <- runDB $ getBy $ UniqueUserId userId
                 case mProfile of
                   Just (Entity pid _) -> pid
                   Nothing -> undefined
   |
45 |     mProfile <- runDB $ getBy $ UniqueUserId userId
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What am I doing wrong? What's the proper way to do this query?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [runDB's type signature](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-persistent-1.6.0.2/docs/Yesod-Persist-Core.html#v:runDB):

```hs
runDB :: YesodDB site a -> HandlerFor site a
```

you'll see what the problem is.

Yesod requires you to do some rather elaborate stuff to actually use the query's results - it isn't simply a (Maybe result). You can find examples [here](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent); this part in particular:

```hs
people <- runDB $ selectList [] [Asc PersonAge]
defaultLayout
        [whamlet|
            <ul>
                $forall Entity personid person <- people
                    <li>
                        <a href=@{PersonR personid}>#{personFirstName person}
        |]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!
I changed the type signature and it is compiling.

Answer (score 0):

This is compiling

```
getOrCreateProfile :: UserId -> Handler ProfileId
getOrCreateProfile userId = runDB $ do
    mProfile <- getBy $ UniqueUserId userId
    case mProfile of
        Just (Entity pid _) -> return pid
        Nothing  -> insert $ Profile getTempProfile userId
```